# Is there any way to get historical pool data by interacting with the pool smart contract?

Tags: web3js, contract-development, web3.py

I am wondering if there is a function in smart contract pools to get historical data (just last 100 bars for example).
thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. This is not as much specifically a function in a smart contract but more like querying any contract function against a specific block. You need an archive node (instead of a full node) for that as an archive node contains all network states (identified by blocks) in the past that you can do a query against.

Let's use a Uniswap V3 LP for USDC-WETH as an example: [0x88e6A0c2dDD26FEEb64F039a2c41296FcB3f5640](https://etherscan.io/address/0x88e6a0c2ddd26feeb64f039a2c41296fcb3f5640).

The function that you call to get the USDC-WETH exchange rate is `slot0()` (remember, the returned data is hex and square root).

Let's use [eth_call](https://docs.chainstack.com/reference/ethereum-ethcall) to do a simple curl call to `slot0()` to get the exchange rate from the USDC-WETH pool.

**Template**

```
curl -X POST ARCHIVE_NODE_ENDPOINT \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data '{
  "jsonrpc":"2.0",
  "method":"eth_call",
  "params":[{
    "to": "CONTRACT_ADDRESS",
    "data":"FUNCTION_SIGNATURE"
  }, "BLOCK_NUMBER"],
  "id":1
}'
```

where:

- ARCHIVE_NODE_ENDPOINT — you need an archive node.
- CONTRACT_ADDRESS — An LP contract address. `0x88e6A0c2dDD26FEEb64F039a2c41296FcB3f5640` in our case.
- FUNCTION_SIGNATURE — convert `slot0` to the function signature. For example, [use an online tool](https://web3tools.chainstacklabs.com/generate-solidity-functions-signature), paste `slot0` in `Function name and parameters type` and get `0x3850c7bd`.
- BLOCK_NUMBER — block number in hex or just `latest`.

**Curl example**

Here's the exchange rate of USDC-WETH at block `12489829`.

```
curl -X POST ARCHIVE_NODE_ENDPOINT \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data '{
  "jsonrpc":"2.0",
  "method":"eth_call",
  "params":[{
    "to": "0x88e6A0c2dDD26FEEb64F039a2c41296FcB3f5640",
    "data":"0x3850c7bd"
  }, "0xBE9465"],
  "id":1
}'
```

As a side note, you need an archive node to go beyond the immediate 128 blocks in the past to get the data. If you are on the Ethereum mainnet (and on Geth, Erigon nodes) and query for state within the 128 blocks, you can get by with a full node. A full node prunes states past the 128 blocks by default, although this also depends on the node config.

**Python example with exchange rate conversion**

If you want to get actual exchange rate printed, here's Python code that gets the result with `eth_call` (same as the curl example) and then converts it following the [Uniswap V3 primer](https://blog.uniswap.org/uniswap-v3-math-primer).

```
import json
from web3 import Web3

# Load the UniswapV3Pool ABI from local file. You can get the ABI from https://etherscan.io/address/0x88e6A0c2dDD26FEEb64F039a2c41296FcB3f5640#code
with open('UniswapV3Pool_abi.json', 'r') as file:
    contract_abi = json.load(file)

# Have an Ethereum mainnet archive node here so we can fetch from any block in the past, not just the immediate past 128 blocks
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("ARCHIVE_NODE_ENDPOINT"))

# UniswapV3Pool for USDC-WETH
contract_address = "0x88e6A0c2dDD26FEEb64F039a2c41296FcB3f5640"

contract = w3.eth.contract(address=contract_address, abi=contract_abi)

# Make the eth_call to slot0 at block 12489829 (put any block)
result = contract.functions.slot0().call(block_identifier=12489829)

# Parse the result from the returned value following the struct https://etherscan.io/address/0x88e6A0c2dDD26FEEb64F039a2c41296FcB3f5640#code#F1#L58 // basically just getting the first value
sqrtPriceX96 = result[0]

# Calculate the price following https://blog.uniswap.org/uniswap-v3-math-primer
price = (sqrtPriceX96 / (2**96))**2

# Adjust for token decimals because USDC is 6 decimals and WETH is 18 decimals
adjPrice = price / 1e12

# Convert the price per WETH token to a more readable format
exchange_rate = 1 / adjPrice

# Print the exchange rate with 2f as a two-decimal floating number just for human readability
print(f'The exchange rate is {exchange_rate:.2f} USDC per WETH.')
```

Comment: thank you so much for the help, I managed to pull the data for the example above, the result is : 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000005699958e9f83ba1dea1c769656110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000030dcb00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
But I am not able to convert to readable format

Comment: You said the returned data is hex and square root, I tried to covert the data to readable format but no luck, I also used alchemy api for the archive node

Comment: I finally managed to convert the hex value to float and after square root the result is :
 6.506616883820552382941721992E+247
it's false obviously the value of eth should be around 1650 I think

Comment: I added Python code to do the conversion too.

Comment: I apologize for inconveniencing, the result of the code is this : "Exchange Rate USDC-WETH: 2.6074282406289621803866375815174726108106586707927E+962"
still not able to understand how to interpret it, thank you for the valuable help

Comment: @AnissItaoui apologies for the sloppy code. The biggest one was not accounting for USDC having 6 decimals (instead of the default 18 decimals for most ERC20 tokens, including WETH). The other issue was I stopped at just the first value in the result sqrtPriceX96 and left the remaining struct parts in. A better approach is to parse the result, get the first value (sqrtPriceX96) and convert it. I updated the code in the answer section, and now it's using web3.py too. It works now. Let me know.

Comment: thank you so much!! it's working perfectly, still have to understand some lines, if I fail to understand something I will probably just ask you here and hope for a response, you are amazing, thanks again